# EmberJS - Creating/Accessing Objects from Nested Array within an Object and Acting on it

Tags: ember.js

My JSON object that is returned from the server looks like this:

```js
[
  { 
    "id" : 1, 
    "name": "Biking", 
    "type": [{ 
      "id" : 1, 
      "name" : "Road"
    }]
  },
  { 
    "id" : 2, 
    "name": "MotorCycling",
    "type": [{ 
      "id" : 1, 
      "name" : "MX", 
      "alias" : { 
        "name": "Dirt", 
        "showaliasonsportid": [1,2,3] 
        } 
    }
  ]}
]
```

My ember js looks like this

```js
App.Activity = Em.Object.extend({
});

App.ActivityListView = Em.View.extend({ 
});

App.activitiesController = Em.ArrayProxy.create({ 
    content: [],

    loadActivities: function () {
      var self = this;
      $.getJSON('data/activities.json', function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(item) {
          self.pushObject(App.Activity.create(item));
        });
      });
    }
});
```

My question is how can I act on the showaliasonsportid array or even access it to display the alias.name instead of the type.name value?  I have read that I may need to create an object out of the alias and or showaliasonsportid array but I am confused on how to do this with Ember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Ember Data, it solves these sort of problems very well: https://github.com/emberjs/data

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. I originally looked at the ember-data add on but the DS.Model url property needed to be in this format url: data/activity and the ember-data script would pluralize this to data/activitys. I do not have control of the data url so I abandoned ember-data.  Can you write a custom function for the URL handler?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the github page you can see how you can define your own url/adapter/logic.